# I can't set a border to Jpanel in java

Tags: java, netbeans, jpanel

[image]

according to the picture above, when I click on border property, it dosesn't show me border and title border to select the border and show this picture above.
before it did work correctly and show border to select
I don't know what is the problem with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using netbeans, you can click on **Design tab**, click on the **JPanel** either in the **frame/Design area** or from the **Navigator** and look for **Border attribute** in the **Pallete window**. Click the **ellipsis button** here. You get your desired window. Hope this helps.

Comment: i did exactly like this,but it's show me the first picture.

Comment: I think you are not having your properties window visible. Here are the steps, Right click on your **JPanel** and choose **Properties**. You get four tabs here namely **Properties ,Binding,Events,Code** . Make sure you have the **Properties tab** highlighted. Then find your **Border attribute**.

Answer (score 0):

it was my fault
instead of I click on properties tab, I clicked on the binding tab and I looked forward it.
what the stupid man I am.